# Maximized windows by default on Ubuntu 22.04 with Gnome?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, maximized, tiling, workflow

I like to always see one maximized window at a time on my screen. It keeps me focused. How can I make all new windows be maximized by default, i.e without pressing the keyboard shortcut for maximize or using the mouse? On Ubuntu 20.04 I could use the Gnome extension "Maximized by Default" but it does not support Gnome 42, and it does not seem to be maintained anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gnome extension [Maximized by default](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1193/maximized-by-default/) still works for Gnome 42 on my PopOS 22.04, both if I run `gsettings set org.gnome.shell disable-extension-version-validation true`, and if I download from the extensions website or from Github and install as described in [Manually install a Gnome Shell Extension from a ZIP file](https://www.pragmaticlinux.com/2021/06/manually-install-a-gnome-shell-extension-from-a-zip-file/).